# Trying not to show the buttons showing when I click in one of the EditText of the form

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, button, android-edittext

I'm working on an Android app with Android Studio. I have a form with several field and 2 buttons at the bottom to either validate or going back. The problem is that as soon as I click in one of the EditText of the form, the 2 buttons are following the keyboard.

[image]

How to prevent these 2 buttons to show up and force them to stay at the bottom of the page, hidden behind the keyboard. The form is in a ScrollView, which is in a ConstraintLayout. I tried many things like having my 2 buttons in the ConstraintLayout. Also outside in a RelativeLayout with constraint at the bottom of the parent... I also tried to use LinearLayout instead of the ConstraintLayout and weight each component but the buttons are still there. The only way I found is to use a vertical LinearLayout without weighting the components. But then I have the problem of not seeing the buttons if the screen is too small. I would like buttons to stay at the bottom.

Is it normal? Do I have to fix it from the code by hiding the buttons when focusing on one of the TextEdit, or by the layouts?

The other thing is that if I click on the last field ("Ville"), the form doesn't move and I still see the first 2 lines...

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your `manifest.xml` you can set `android:windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustPan`.

```
<activity
 android:name=".MainActivity"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

From Android documentation:

> Don't resize the window to make room for the soft input area; instead
> pan the contents of the window as focus moves inside of it so that the
> user can see what they are typing. This is generally less desireable
> than panning because the user may need to close the input area to get
> at and interact with parts of the window

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I needed. It solved both problems I had.

Comment: I will of course, but I have to wait 5 min apparently :)